# Which port is needed to allow in firewall to run rabbitmq management panel?

Tags: rabbitmq, firewall

I am running rabbitmq as a service in CentOS 7 after allowing port `5672` in firewall.

But I am facing problem when I am trying to run the management panel after allowing the default port `15672` to firewall, but it doesn't work.I have also tried allowing `25672`,`4369` etc.

However, if I stop the firewall, management panel appears successfully.

What else port should I allow?

N.B. selinux is set to disabled.

Answer (score 0):

it only needs port 15672. if the firewall isn't allowing it, then you might need to check the configuration to make sure it allows all traffic - tcp and upd - coming in and going out of that port for the rabbitmq (erlang) processes.

personally, i spent an entire week trying to get this working on a redhat box, with selinux enabled. what a nightmare. eventually figured it out, but that was so long ago i don't remember exactly how i got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Allow 5672, 15672 TCP port in windows firewall.. its works for me.